# How to change the url of an app in Django to custom url

Tags: python, django, url

I have an app in my Django project that called Stressz. So the url of my app is:

```
http://localhost:8000/stressz/
http://localhost:8000/stressz/siker
http://localhost:8000/stressz/attitud
```

How can I change the url without changing the name of the app from the above url to something like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/mpa
http://localhost:8000/mpa/siker
http://localhost:8000/mpa/attitud
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'stressz'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('siker', views.siker, name='siker'),
    path('attitud', login_required(views.AttitudCreateView.as_view()), name='attitud_item'),
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into your root urls.py, which you can usually find in your project (not app) folder. There has to be a line similar to this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('stressz', include('stressz.urls')),
]
```

If you then change it to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('mpa', include('stressz.urls')),
]
```

It should work as you intended.

Answer (score 0):

You can also avoid typing this name by redirection. Still you can change the name to "mpa" as explained by dustin-we.

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='stressz'), name='main'),
    path('stressz/', include('stressz.urls')),
]
```